# Restrict access to static site on S3 using presigned URLs?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a site that has iframed static websites available on it. Basically, these 'sites' are magazine publications that are HTML based and we just iframe them into a page for our authenticated users. This is not an ideal scenario and is considered temporary.

What we're trying to do is to use S3 for hosting these publications for various
reasons.

Now, its entirely possible and super easy to grab a presigned url for the index page but of course all of the linked images, styles and js fail to load. What I'm wondering is whether there is a way I can embed these 'sites' without creating a user for each of our members in aws and without re-writing the HTML to use presigned urls for the attached resources.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a direct to S3 approach take a look at using [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) as a layer in front of your static site(s).

CloudFront like S3 supports pre signed URLs, however it also includes a feature called [signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html).

By using a signed cookie all assets can be accessed by their existing URLs (without having to replace in the HTML content), instead the signed cookie will validate on the pageload and display all content from the specific domain.

Comment: Oooh that sounds perfect. I'll check that out thanks!